# How to sort array with respective array ids or values?

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

I have two arrays:

```
 String [] ids= new String [5];
 String [] points= new String [5];

 String one="a,b,c,d,e";
 //or
 String one="nepal,japan,finland ,brazil,spain";
 String two="100,500,200,400,300";
 ids= one.split(",");
 points= two.split(",");
```

Now i want to sort `points` in descending order just like.

```
500,400,300,200,100 with respective ids b,d,e,c,a
```

how can i do that.

But i try this point descending order which is ok, but how to ordered ids with respective id.

```
 Arrays.sort(points, Collections.reverseOrder());
 Arrays.toString(points);
```

or

```
Arrays.sort(points);
```

if i do same as ids which is also descending. but which is not output.

**Edited:**

if i have replace

a,b,c,d,e letter to contries name or time.

```
String one="a,b,c,d,e";
//  or
String countries = "nepal,japan,finland,brazil,spain";
// or
String time="0:10,1:25,4:00,2:10,0:55";
```

Comment: Whomever up voted this; since you apparently understand whatever this is asking, can you explain it?

Comment: @BrianRoach He wants to sort one array, and have another array of the same size in the same order when he's done.

Comment: @bdares - Thanks ... I was having a problem deciphering it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your own `Comparator`, something like this:

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class CustomArrayComparator implements Comparator<String>
{
    private String[] pointsArray;
    private Map<String, Integer> idsMap;

    public CustomArrayComparator(String[] pointsArray, String[] countriesArray)
    {
        this.pointsArray = pointsArray;
        idsMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        for(int i = 0; i < pointsArray.length; i++) idsMap.put(countriesArray[i], i);
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2)
    {   
        return pointsArray[idsMap.get(s2)].compareTo(pointsArray[idsMap.get(s1)]);
    }
}
```

and here is the main:

```
String[] points = {"100", "500", "200", "400", "300"};
String[] countries = {"nepal", "japan", "finland", "brazil", "spain"};
CustomArrayComparator comparator = new CustomArrayComparator(points, countries);
Arrays.sort(countries, comparator);
Arrays.sort(points, Collections.reverseOrder());

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(points));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(countries));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[500, 400, 300, 200, 100]
[japan, brazil, spain, finland, nepal]
```

---

**EDIT:**

As a general class, here is the same class with generic implementation:

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class CustomArrayComparator<T extends Comparable<T>, E> implements Comparator<T>
{
    private T[] mainArray;
    private Map<E, Integer> indexesMap;

    public CustomArrayComparator(T[] mainArray, E[] associatedArray)
    {
        this.mainArray = mainArray;
        indexesMap = new HashMap<E, Integer>();
        for(int i = 0; i < mainArray.length; i++)
        {
            indexesMap.put(associatedArray[i], i);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(T t1, T t2)
    {   
        return mainArray[indexesMap.get(t2)].compareTo(mainArray[indexesMap.get(t1)]);
    }
}
```

The main:

```
String[] points = {"100", "500", "200", "400", "300"};
String[] countries = {"nepal", "japan", "finland", "brazil", "spain"};
Comparator<String> comparator = new CustomArrayComparator<String, String>(points, countries);
Arrays.sort(countries, comparator);
Arrays.sort(points, Collections.reverseOrder());

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(points));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(countries));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[500, 400, 300, 200, 100]
[japan, brazil, spain, finland, nepal]
```

Comment: Nice huh....if i replace ids array to usa, india, japan, finland , germany then what to do?? am i right , replacae createCharacterArray()to createStringArray().

Comment: But you put one argument on custom class. which is points but after creating new instances you assigning two argument. how is it possible?

Comment: @KshetriHorrorgoogle Because I edited the answer, see the final update

Comment: @KshetriHorrorgoogle see the final update for the general implementaton

Answer (score 2):

`Arrays.sort()` will only sort the one array you give it.  I would create a class that has both `id` and `point` fields, an array (or Collection) of that class, and sort that array.  You'll also have to implement `comparable`.

Alternatively, you can have a mapping between the two arrays.  Sort the `points` array, then reorder the `ids` array to match the mapping.  (This is slightly more expensive but possibly easier to understand.)

Comment: Personally I think the former is easier to understand if you grok OOP at all.

Answer (score 1):

Define yourself a custom class (or something generic like a Pair<T1, T2> and define a comparator that sorts by the first value.  Then you can do Arrays.sort(arrayOfPairs, pairComparator)